# How to extract information from a text file that is located on a web page in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am a total beginner and I'm trying to do the following. I need to open a text file from a web page which contains a small list like that below.

- name lastname M 0909
- name lastname C 0909
- name lastname F 0909
- name lastname M 0909
- name lastname M 0909

What I need to do is to count how many big M letters and how many big different letters there is(here is 3 M,F and C)and print it out. Then I need to create a new text file and transfer (only) all the names into it and save it on my hard drive. So far I only figured out how to open the list from web page.

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://mypage.com/python/textfile.txt' 
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as myfile:
 for i in myfile:
    i = i.decode("ISO-8859-1")
    print(i,end=" ")
```

But that is all I know. I tried using count() but it counts only one line at the time, it counts how many big M letters are in one line(1) but it does not add them together for the whole text(3). Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are doing, but try this:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://mypage.com/python/textfile.txt'   
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as myfile:
number_of_M = 0
set_of_big_letters = set()
for i in myfile:
    i = i.decode("ISO-8859-1")
    name, lastname, big_letter, _ = i.split(' ') # if they are seperated by space
    set_of_big_letters.add(big_letter)
    if big_letter == 'M':
        number_of_M += 1

print(number_of_M)
print(len(set_of_big_letters))
```